# Flutter rendering an encrypted Image

Tags: flutter, image, networking, encryption, networkimageview

Hey guys I have a scenario where I have to load an image from a url in flutter app. So I can use Image.network for this. But in my case I’ll get the image response as encrypted string. I’ll have to decrypt the response and then populate the image in the UI. Is there any way I can override the Image.network and override the method which will get called on image downloaded and decrypt the image string and then render it ? Ps I’m not looking for any third party libraries for this.

I know we can simply make a normal rest call download the byte stream and then decrypt and render it on UI. But I don’t want to take that approach. I wanted to do this by overriding image.network. Please let me know if there is any way to do this. Couldn’t find any working solution for this,Thanks.